# How to include multiple priors in bayesian

Tags: python, linear-regression, bayesian, pymc3

I'm trying to do a Bayesian regression in Python. I have included multiple priors for the same outcome (`y`) variable but the posterior mean doesn't seem to change. Could someone comment on my implementation?

```python
import pymc3 as pm

formula = schooling_y_r5 ~ xvariable

with pm.Model() as normal_model:
    
    my_priors= {
        'Intercept': pm.Normal.dist(mu=0., sigma=100.),
        'schooling_y_r5': pm.Normal.dist(mu=14, sigma=3.8) ,
        'schooling_y_r5': pm.Normal.dist(mu=17, sigma=3.8) ,
        'schooling_y_r5': pm.Normal.dist(mu=7.8, sigma=3.8) ,
        'schooling_y_r5': pm.Normal.dist(mu=7.6, sigma=3.8) 
    }
    
   
    
    # Creating the model requires a formula and data (and optionally a family)
    pm.GLM.from_formula(formula, data = X_train, priors=my_priors)
    
    # Perform Markov Chain Monte Carlo sampling letting PyMC3 choose the algorithm
    normal_trace = pm.sample(draws=3000, chains = 2, tune = 4000)
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what the expected behavior is here. First, I don't understand a prior directly on an outcome variable - priors are usually only on parameters of the model for the observed. Second, what should having multiple definitions of the same prior do? Are they all evaluated, so that they multiply the likelihood? Or are you expecting it to generate and evaluate a separate model for each prior? But again, the observations are fixed, so any likelihood contributed by priors on the observation would be constant (i.e., can be freely ignored).

Comment: Hey Merv thanks for replying to my question. This is the research problem im trying to analyse. I have an independent variable X stunting (yes or no) and outcome variable (Y) height. We are trying to study the effect of stunting on outcome variable using Bayesian.

Comment: Hey Merv thanks for replying to my question. This is the research problem im trying to analyse. I have an independent variable X stunting (yes or no) and outcome variable (Y) height. We are trying to study the effect of stunting on outcome variable using Bayesian regression. The outcome variable is for one city of brazil. We have prior information which is average height of the country. So what you see in the code above is average height from multiple sources. Is this the right way of implementation. What we are trying to do is use the prior incorporated model and one without prior to compare

Comment: Any help would be greatly apprecited